# License concerns for Ubuntu/Linux and a prospective business

Tags: license, open-source, legal

Having a hard time finding specifics, could someone link me to some materials concerning licensing issues of Ubuntu, and link's at large?

I'm considering starting a business installing custom/embedded computer systems, and the open source nature of various Linux distros makes them the most attractive candidates  for final installation. I just want to make sure it would be legal to do so.

Would I be able to charge for installation of the OS? If not, could I provide the customer the physical means for installation (CD, USB)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can charge for it.  The only restriction is that you must provide your customers with the source code to the software.  Provided that you don't modify it, that is already handled by Canonical and the Ubuntu archive mirrors.

See also:

http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/our-philosophy

Comment: would the inclusion  of the source code in the installation be sufficient. Also, thanks for the link!

Comment: @user59886, yes, or publishing it on the web for download, as Canonical has done.  If you don't make any changes to the code, then you can just point your customers to where you downloaded it from.

Comment: To just clarify an already fine answer, you can charge for anything, even the source code.  But since the requirement is that you have to provide them with the source code, nobody would actually buy the source code if you offered to sell it.

Comment: @Chan-Ho Suh   Haha! I dont think that would be necessary, but amusing /informative just the same. Thank you both.

Answer (score 3):

I would also like to add

http://www.linuxfoundation.org/programs/legal

They are the "official" body for this sort of thing (non-distro related).